# Worklight WL.Client.getUserName

Tags: android, push, ibm-mobilefirst, userid

I have a Worklight 6.2 app.  I am modifying the android java code to subscribe to a notification sent via Bluemix.  After the user logs in, I would like to register the device using the userid that gets created.  Is there an API call that I can use within the android code that is the equivalent to WL.Client.getUserName, or should I be calling the java code from my javascript and passing the userName to the java code?  Thanks for any suggestions.

JT

Comment: Are you following any Bluemix-specific tutorials? How are you implementing your application? Is this a fully native app, or a hybrid app?

Comment: Hi, No Bluemix for this app, although that would be a great exercise to try as well.  This is a WL hybrid application using JQuery Mobile Framework.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Java equivalent to this. This is a Worklight API.

- What you can do is use the new [`WL.App.sendActionToNative`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html%23sendActionToNative) method in Worklight 6.2 for to send a value to your native code and from there do what you need with it.

  ```
  WL.App.sendActionToNative(“doSomething”, { customData: 12345} );
  ```

  Where `customdData` is the `WL.Client.getUserName`.
  On the native side you then need to use [`WLActionReciever`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/androidgap/api/WLActionReceiver.html)  (see [What's New](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_wn_api.html)).
- You could also opt to implement a basic Cordova plug-in that will move data from the web to native view.
  [The tutorial in the Getting Started page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid) is doing exactly that.

Comment: Thanks Idan, this is great information.  I'll run through the tutorial.